# Manually numbering with \tag in double dollar signs

Tags: equations, tex-core, rstudio, rmarkdown

I want to manually numbering in non-numbered displayed equation environment and
try the following steps

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[
\bar{D}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} D_{j}, \quad s_{d}^{2}=\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(D_{j}-\bar{D}\right)^{2}
\tag{6-1}
\]

\begin{equation*}
\bar{D}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} D_{j}, \quad s_{d}^{2}=\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(D_{j}-\bar{D}\right)^{2}
\tag{6-1}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Which works successfully.

Since the R Markdown in Rstudio and the Markdown in Typora support
the automatic-displaying of equations in double dollar signs (`$$...$$`),
I sometimes need manually numbering with `\tag` in double dollar signs,
even if I know people prefer to recommend using `\[...\]`
and `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}` instead of using `$$...$$`.

I tried

```
$$
\bar{D}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} D_{j}, \quad s_{d}^{2}=\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(D_{j}-\bar{D}\right)^{2}
\tag{6-1}
$$
```

and it showed normally and correctly in Rstudio (.Rmd) and Typora (.md),
but showing errors in my Texstudio+Texlive2019, with

```
! Package amsmath Error: \tag not allowed here.
```

My question is if I insist using manually numbering with `\tag` in double dollar signs (`$$...$$`),
what should I do?

Comment: I also came up with a way that might work in  Rstudio (.Rmd), Typora (.md) and TeXstudio (.tex) at the same time, with a command added in the preamble as `\renewenvironment{$$}{\[}{\]}`. However, it showed a error `! LaTeX Error: Environment $$ undefined.`

Comment: as wipet says, if you are using tex primitive syntax you can use `\eqno` but it must surely be possible to get R markdown to generate better latex than this. whether you use `$$` or `\[` there should never be a blank line before the display, as it generates a spurious one line paragraph with an empty line just containing an identation box.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Thank you for your reply! I know `\eqno` or `\feqno` for `$$...$$`, but Rstudio (.Rmd) and Typora (.md) don't support the automatic-displaying (i.e., you don't need to compile it!) the manually numbering  with `\eqno` or `\feqno`. Of course, with compilation, there are many better choices other than `$$...$$`. Why I insist using `$$...$$` with `\tag` is to unify Rstudio (.Rmd), Typora (.md) and Texstudio (.tex) without any extra coding overhead.

Comment: but it doesn't have no coding overhead as you need to define it (to be `\eqno` )otherwise it  won't work.

Answer (score 2):

Use TeX primitive `\eqno` instead LaTeX macro `\tag`:

```
$$
\bar{D}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} D_{j}, \quad s_{d}^{2}=\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(D_{j}-\bar{D}\right)^{2}
\eqno\hbox{(6-1)}
$$
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer!  Please see my responses to David Carlisle. Tks again!